# Reading, echoing, and returning integers in an array

Tags: beginner, c, array, memory-management, pointers

I was wanting some clarification on my code, as I am new to pointers in C. I am trying to return an array from a simple function just so I can understand exactly what it is that I'm doing.

Here is the code I have so far and, to me, it seems as if I haven't even used the pointers correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *myFunction(int size)
{
    int i;
    int *myArray = malloc(sizeof(int)*size);
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter a number: ");
        scanf("%d",&myArray[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",myArray[i]);
    }
    return myArray;
}
int main()
{
    int *p;
    int size;
    printf("Enter the size: ");
    scanf("%d",&size);
    p = myFunction(size);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @MORTAL All concrete suggestions for improvements belong in answers. I've deleted the ensuing thread, which ended up discussing your suggestion rather than the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Someone suggested I turn my comment into an answer, so here goes.

First, I simply ran your code through `astyle` and added line numbers to make it easier to
reference in the text. Hopefully you can see from the output how a little bit of white-space
and consistent formatting/indentation can make your code clearer.

```
 1  #include <stdio.h>
 2  #include <stdlib.h>
 3  
 4  int *myFunction(int size)
 5  {
 6      int i;
 7      int *myArray = malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
 8  
 9      for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
10      {
11          printf("Enter a number: ");
12          scanf("%d", &myArray[i]);
13      }
14  
15      for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
16      {
17          printf("%d\n", myArray[i]);
18      }
19  
20      return myArray;
21  }
22  
23  int main()
24  {
25      int *p;
26      int size;
27      printf("Enter the size: ");
28      scanf("%d", &size);
29      p = myFunction(size);
30      return 0;
31  }
```

First, full marks for lines 23 and 30: many people still code as if `main` can be declared `void main()` and
fail to return an exit code. This would be just a little better for line 30.

```
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

As I said above, there is nothing wrong with your use of pointers (which was your primary concern). But there are
other issues with the code if this was ever to be used for anything other than exploring concepts.

Now, let's deal with dynamic memory.

MORTAL suggested zeroing all dyamically allocated memory. That can be useful (for example, if you are going
to build a c-style string in the buffer) but is not necessarily a "good thing" in all cases. However, we can
clean up line 7 a little and get that for free while we're at it. In this line, you are allocating memory to
hold an array of `int` - rather than just a chunk of memory.

There's a function just for that purpose, so this

```
int *myArray = calloc(size, sizeof(int))
```

very clearly expresses your need for enough memory to store `size` `int`s.

It also sets the memory block to all zeroes before returning it.

As ChrisWue mentioned, `size` could be a **very large number** such that the call to `malloc` or `calloc` could fail.
So it's a best practice to always check the returned pointer to see if it is NULL (that's how memory allocation
routines report failure). So now we have:

```
int *myArray = calloc(size, sizeof(int))

if (!myArray)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory to hold your input. Exiting.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Note that I simply bail out (indicating an error via the exit status) rather than try and deal with an out of memory
condition. In fact, there's an even chance that the `fprintf` won't work if your system is this low on resources
but it's worth trying to say *something* rather than just present the user with a commmand line prompt.

Having got over that hurdle, you should always return any dynamically allocated memory to the pool as soon as you 
are finished with it. Most operating systems will release all resources when a process ends ... but what you are
looking at in your code is a classic "memory leak".

As the caller does nothing with the returned array, I would actually make a few changes.

- Change the return type of `myFunction` to `void`
- Replace line 20 with `free(myArray);` to release the allocated memory
- Delete line 25, and modify the call on line 29 not to save the (now non-existent) return value

Also, as a general rule, `int` is the wrong type for indexing arrays. First, it is signed and
`myArray[-1]` makes no sense. Second, and `int` may not be large enough to index all of memory.
The correct type to use is `size_t`, and indeed that's what `calloc` and `malloc` expect.

So your variables `size` and `i` should be `size_t`, and line 28 should change to read

```
scanf("%zu", &size);
```

where `"%zu"` is the correct format code for a `size_t`.

Your code now looks like this:

```
 1  #include <stdio.h>
 2  #include <stdlib.h>
 3  
 4  void myFunction(size_t size)
 5  {
 6      size_t i;
 7      int *myArray;
 8  
 9      myArray  = calloc(size, sizeof(int));
10      if (!myArray)
11      {
12          fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory to hold your input. Exiting.\n");
13          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
14      }
15  
16      for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
17      {
18          printf("Enter a number: ");
19          scanf("%d", &myArray[i]);
20      }
21  
22      for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
23      {
24          printf("%d\n", myArray[i]);
25      }
26  
27      free(myArray);
28  }
29  
30  int main()
31  {
32      size_t size;
33      printf("Enter the size: ");
34      scanf("%zu", &size);
35      printf("You need to enter %zu numbers\n", size);
36      myFunction(size);
37      return EXIT_SUCCESS;
38  }
```

Note that I added line 35 to give a little more feedback.

There is a bigger problem with your use of `scanf` that goes beyond the scope of this review. Just be
aware that `scanf` (like `gets()`) is considered **EVIL**. Just as a simple example, try these
responses to your "Enter the size:" prompt (leave out the quotes)

- "a very long string"
- "10 followed by some text"
- "-1"

Comment: A note of interest is that if you're using visual studio for your code `%zu` is not supported. This is part of the C99 standard which Microsoft does not support. You must use `%lu` in Visual Studio. Additional information http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15610053/correct-printf-format-specifier-for-size-t-zu-or-iu

Answer (score 6):

Make use of Spaces,  just figured I would get it out of the way so others can focus on the meat of the code.

By spaces I mean in your for declarations and parameter lists.

so this

```
for(i=0;i<size;i++)
```

Becomes this:

```
for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
```

And this

```
printf("%d\n",myArray[i]);
```

Becomes this:

```
printf("%d\n", myArray[i]);
```

---

and this

```
for(i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d",&myArray[i]);
}
for(i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    printf("%d\n",myArray[i]);
}
```

looks funny to me, I don't know about pointers though. but I am guessing that there is a way to merge these together so that you are not going through 2 loops.  you could probably make this a single loop somehow, but that would change the output of the code.

Comment: If this was made a single loop, it would echo the number entered before asking for the next one, which is probably not what the OP intended.

Comment: @kdopen, not if you did it in the same order, it would wait until the user put the number in and then print it and then loop again.

Comment: But the current code gets *all* inputs, and then prints them all out.

Comment: @kdopen I mentioned that changing the loops would change the output of the code.

Answer (score 5):

1. The user inputs the size. This means that `malloc` may fail due to some very large number being supplied. If `malloc` fails to allocate the requested amount of memory it will return `NULL` and your code will very likely crash. Hence you should always check the return value of `malloc` (and other standard library functions as well for that matter) and bail out if it's `NULL`.
2. Currently you return the allocated array to the caller but you do not `free` the memory anywhere. Given that your program is finished at this point the OS will do the cleanup for you but it's nicer to `free` all memory you allocate.